# Google Earth API stopped working - shows page but no map

Tags: google-maps

I have an application that is using the Google Maps API.  It was working fine until recently, but have now (in the last 3 weeks or so) stopped working.  I did not make any changes to the code, so I assume the change was on Google's side.

I have tried to get it up and running again, but I'm not winning.  The page loads, but does not display the map (it only displays the controls).  I have reduced the code to the bare minimum (i.e. removed all my dropped pin and return coordinates code), but I'm still stuck.  I don't get any error messages either.

The code is provided here is a watered down version, where I've tried to keep just the basics.  It is written in Delphi XE5 (VCL), and uses a Webbrowser components with the following HTML script.  Where MY_KEY is defined I use an API key from Google:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
<!--      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; } -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}   
    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?Key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Please see the attached screenshot[image: Reduced software where Google Maps don't show]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 8764 in issue tracker: white layers comes on top of google map](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8754)

The Webbrowser component renders in IE7 mode.  That is no longer supported by the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  See the issue for a work around.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is exactly the issue, but why I couldn't find this in my Google attempts is still a mystery.